# ldap objectclass with "contact type" attribute

Tags: attributes, ldap

Trying to do something with OpenLDAP that should be very simple, just can't seem to find a clear answer. I need to be able to organize any person's contact attributes according to their "type". For example, email would be type 6. So, if I wanted to send an email to all members of my OU, I would choose those that have a type 6 address.

since LDAP attributes are a name, value pair, I don't see how to assign an additional property to a contact address, yet it seems like a common enough problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes in the directory server model are indeed name [optional option] value constructs. To accomplish the task you describe, you could assign another attribute to the entry. [RFC2798](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798) defines the `employeeType` ([link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798#section-2.5)) attribute type with a syntax of `DirectoryString` and an equality matching rule of `caseIgnoreMatch`. Perhaps this attribute could be used for your purposes. If you assigned the attribute like:

```
employeeType: type 6
```

the LDAP client would then find all those employees with a filter like

```
(&(employeeType=type 6)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)).
```

If you had concerns about the matching being `caseIgnoreMatch` you could specify that the server use `caseExactMatch` by using an extensible match filter like:

```
(&(employeeType:caseExactMatch:=type 6)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))
```

`employeeType` is multi-valued, therefore, employees could have more than one `employeeType`. Any value that is a valid [DirectoryString](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#section-3.3.6) could be assigned to `employeeType`.

Comment: Thanks, that works for a person, but what about if I need to have a record for a person with a phone number and email, and I want the phone number to be flagged as contact type 10, and email as contact type 35?

Comment: To meet this requirement, it may be necessary to define new attributes to hold information about contact types. If new attributes are defined in the schema they could be named `companyNameHereMailContactType`, `companyNameHereTelephoneNumberContactType`. Alternatively, the format of the `employeeType` attribute value could be `mailContactType type 6'` and another `employeeType` attribute with value `telephoneNumberContactType type 10` and so forth. There are a number of ways to accomplish what I think you are describing. Or I could be misunderstanding you entirely.

Comment: you're understanding me just fine. and my question stems precisely from multitude of options. Contact point is an object and a person is an object. in an object oriented universe person would have a contact point property which would hold the contact point info. Question is what's the best way to do this in the name/value pair world of LDAP.

Comment: Perhaps I can refrase my question: Can I create a ContactPoint object (with its attributes including type) and define a new property for inetOrgPerson (or a custom class based on it) that holds a ContactPoint object?

Comment: Yes. Define a new objectClass `ContactPoint` that has as its superior `inetOrgPerson`. The objectClass definition has clauses that specify attributes that must be allowed and attribute that may be allowed, as well as some other information.